# Union types and Intersection types

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, type-systems

What are the various use cases for union types and intersection types? There has been lately a lot of buzz about these type system features, yet somehow I have never felt need for either of these!

Comment: When you say "union types", do you mean "disjoint union/sum" as in ML algebraic datatypes, or untagged union as with C `union` ?

Comment: Are you looking for examples? This is a very broad question. It's like asking, what are the use cases for product types, or (maybe something you're more familiar with) C `struct`s. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: @Jonathan: Let me rephrase. What do union types and intersection types let me achieve that I cannot do otherwise? Or what things are made easier by union types and intersection types that are comparatively harder to do in type systems without these features?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a more practice-oriented answer:

With union and recursive types you can encode regular tree types and therefore XML types.

With intersection types you can type BOTH overloaded functions and refinement types (what in a previous post is called coherent overloading)

So for instance you can write the function add (that overloads integer sum and string concatenation) as follows

```
let add ( (Int,Int)->Int ; (String,String)->String )
      | (x & Int, y & Int) -> x+y
      | (x & String, y & String) -> x@y ;;
```

Which has the intersection type

> (Int,Int)->Int & (String,String)->String

But you can also refine the type above and type the function above as

```
(Pos,Pos) -> Pos & 
(Neg,Neg) -> Neg & 
(Int,Int)->Int & 
(String,String)->String.
```

where Pos and Neg are positive and negative integer types.

The code above is executable in the language CDuce ( http://www.cduce.org ) whose type system includes union, intersections, and negation types (it is mainly targeted at XML transformations).

If you want to try it and you are on Linux, then it is probably included in your distribution (apt-get install cduce or yum install cduce should do the work) and you can use its toplevel (a la OCaml) to play with union and intersection types. On the CDuce site you will find a lot of practical examples of use of union and intersection types. And since there is a complete integration with OCaml libraries (you can import OCaml libraries in CDuce and export CDuce modules to OCaml) you can also check the correspondence with ML sum types (see [here](http://cduce.org/manual_interfacewithocaml.html)).

Here you are a complex example that mix union and intersection types (explained in the page "http://www.cduce.org/tutorial_overloading.html#val"), but to understand it you need to understand regular expression pattern matching, which requires some effort.

```
type Person   = FPerson | MPerson 
type FPerson  = <person gender = "F">[ Name Children ] 
type MPerson  = <person gender = "M">[ Name Children ] 
type Children = <children>[ Person* ] 
type Name     = <name>[ PCDATA ]

type Man = <man name=String>[ Sons Daughters ]
type Woman = <woman name=String>[ Sons Daughters ]
type Sons = <sons>[ Man* ]
type Daughters = <daughters>[ Woman* ]

let fun split (MPerson -> Man ; FPerson -> Woman)
  <person gender=g>[ <name>n <children>[(mc::MPerson | fc::FPerson)*] ] ->
  (* the above pattern collects all the MPerson in mc, and all the FPerson in fc *)
     let tag = match g with "F" -> `woman | "M" -> `man in
     let s = map mc with x -> split x in
     let d = map fc with x -> split x in    
     <(tag) name=n>[ <sons>s  <daughters>d ] ;;
```

In a nutshell it transforms values of type Person into values of type (Man | Women) (where the vertical bar denotes a union type) but keeping the correspondence between genres: split is a function with intersection type

```
MPerson -> Man & FPerson -> Woman
```

Answer (score 21):

**Union Types**

To quote Robert Harper, "Practical Foundations for Programming
Languages", ch 15:

> Most data structures involve
>   alternatives such as the distinction
>   between a leaf and an interior node in
>   a tree, or a choice in the outermost
>   form of a piece of abstract syntax.
>   Importantly, the choice determines the
>   structure of the value. For example,
>   nodes have children, but leaves do
>   not, and so forth. These concepts are
>   expressed by **sum types**, speciﬁcally
>   the binary sum, which offers a choice
>   of two things, and the nullary sum,
>   which offers a choice of no things.

**Booleans**

The simplest sum type is the Boolean,

```
data Bool = True
          | False
```

Booleans have only two valid values, T or F. So instead of representing them as numbers, we can instead use a sum type to more accurately encode the fact there are only two possible values.

**Enumerations**

Enumerations are examples of more general sum types: ones with many, but finite, alternative values.

**Sum types and null pointers**

The best practically motivating example for sum types is discriminating between valid results and error values returned by functions, by distinguishing the failure case.

For example, null pointers and end-of-file characters are hackish encodings of the sum type:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing
             | Just a
```

where we can distinguish between valid and invalid values by using the `Nothing` or `Just` tag to annotate each value with its status.

By using sum types in this way we can rule out null pointer errors entirely, which is a pretty decent motivating example. Null pointers are entirely due to the inability of older languages to express sum types easily.

**Intersection Types**

Intersection types are much newer, and their applications are not as widely understood. However, Benjamin Pierce's thesis ("Programming with Intersection Types
and Bounded Polymorphism") gives a good overview:

> The most intriguing and potentially
>   useful property of intersection types
>   is their ability to express an
>   essentially unbounded (though of
>   course ﬁnite) amount of information
>   about the components of a program.
>
> For
>   example, the addition function `(+)` can be
>   given the type `Int -> Int -> Int ^ Real -> Real -> Real`, capturing both the
>   general fact that the sum of two real
>   numbers is always a real and the more
>   specialized fact that the sum of two
>   integers is always an integer. A
>   compiler for a language with
>   intersection types might even provide
>   two different object-code sequences
>   for the two versions of `(+)`, one using a
>   ﬂoating point addition instruction and
>   one using integer addition. For each
>   instance of+ in a program, the
>   compiler can decide whether both
>   arguments are integers and generate
>   the more efﬁcient object code sequence
>   in this case.
>
> This kind of ﬁnitary
>   polymorphism or coherent overloading
>   is so expressive, that ... the set of
>   all valid typings for a program
>   amounts to a complete characterization
>   of the program’s behavior

They let us encode a lot of information in the type, explaining via type theory what multiple inheritance means, giving types to type classes,

Comment: Sum types aren't union types. See [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~joshuad/papers/intcomp/] for a full treatment of union and intersection types.

Comment: That link is dead, try: http://www.mpi-sws.org/~joshua/ -- In case of further link rot, author's name is Joshua Dunfield

Comment: https://people.mpi-sws.org/~joshua/ is dead, but http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~joshuad/papers/intcomp/ is alive.

Comment: @naasking, to which of Joshua Dunfield's papers do you refer?

Comment: @naasking, why do claim that sum types aren't union types?

Comment: Union types express type-level distinctions, sum types express value-level distinctions: https://waleedkhan.name/blog/union-vs-sum-types/

Answer (score 12):

**Union types** are useful for typing dynamic languages or otherwise allowing more flexibility in the types passed around than most static languages allow. For example, consider this:

```
var a;
if (condition) {
  a = "string";
} else {
  a = 123;
}
```

If you have union types, it's easy to type `a` as `int | string`.

One use for **intersection types** is to describe an object that implements multiple interfaces. For example, C# allows multiple [interface constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on generics:

```
interface IFoo {
  void Foo();
}

interface IBar {
  void Bar();
}

void Method<T>(T arg) where T : IFoo, IBar {
  arg.Foo();
  arg.Bar();
}
```

Here, `arg`'s type is the intersection of `IFoo` and `IBar`. Using that, the type-checker knows *both* `Foo()` and `Bar()` are valid methods on it.

Comment: I am very interested at knowing, the source supporting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For instance with union types one could describe json domain model without introducing actual new classes but using only type aliases.

```scala
type JObject = Map[String, JValue]
type JArray = List[JValue]
type JValue = String | Number | Bool | Null | JObject | JArray
type Json = JObject | JArray

def stringify(json: JValue): String = json match {
    case String | Number | Bool | Null => json.toString()
    case JObject => "{" + json.map(x y => x + ": " + stringify(y)).mkStr(", ") + "}"
    case JArray => "[" + json.map(stringify).mkStr(", ") + "]"
}
```

Comment: A code-only answer without any explanation isn't very helpful.

Comment: Please offer some explanation to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).