# What are union types and intersection types?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages, type-systems

What are union types and intersection types?

I have consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653678/union-types-and-intersection-types), but some small working type systems
would be better, not necessary practical ones.

Specifically, by union types I'm referring to the one [mentioned in this blog post](http://yinwang0.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/null/)
instead of sum types, where the pseudo-code looks like

```
{String, null} findName1() {
  if (...) {
    return "okay";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Intersection_types) has a short explanation on intersection types and union
types, but there seems to be no further references about this.

Comment: What exactly can we tell you about the example above? I think it should be pretty clear?

Comment: Yes, the example is pretty clear, but I still don't understand how would intersection types and union types interact (with..perhaps some other types), especially in the presence of (higher-order) function types and parametric polymorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Union and intersection types are just considering types to be sets of values (infinite sets, mostly). If that's how you're thinking of types then any operation on sets that results in a set could be applied to types (sets of values) to make a new type (set of values), at least conceptually.

A union type is similar in some senses to a sum type, which you seem to be familiar with. Indeed I've often heard sum types described as "discriminated union" types. The basic difference is that a sum type like (Haskell notation) `data FooBar = Foo Integer | Bar String` allows you to tell whether a given `FooBar` value contains an `Integer` or a `String` (because `FooBar` values are tagged with `Foo` or `Bar`). Even if we write `data FooBar = Foo Integer | Bar Integer` where both types are the same, the "tag" adds extra information and we can tell "which integer" the `FooBar` value is.

The union type equivalent would be something like (not valid Haskell) `data FooBar = Integer | String`. The values in `FooBar` simply are all the string values and all the integer values. If we make a union type of the same two types like `data FooBar = Integer | Integer` it should be logically indistinguishable from just `Integer`, since the union of a set with itself is itself.

In principle, the things you could do with values in a type U that is the union of types A and B are just the operations that work on As and also work on Bs; any operation that only works on either As or Bs might get the wrong kind of input, because a U has no information to say whether it's an A or a B.<sup>1</sup>

(Undiscriminated) union types wouldn't be very interesting in languages with type systems similar to Haskell's, because concrete types are disjoint<sup>2</sup>, so the only operations that work on both As and Bs work on all values (unless A is B, in which it's just all the operations that work on that single type).

But in a way, a type classes (if you're familiar with them) are a way of providing something a bit like a union type. A type which is polymorphic but constrained to be a member of some type class is a little like a union of all the types which are in the type class (except that you don't know what those are, because type classes are in principle open); the only things you can do with such a value are the thins which have been declared to work on values of *every* type in the type class.

Union types could be interesting in a language with sub-typing (as is common in object-oriented programming languages). If you union together two subtypes of a common super-type you get something that supports at least the operations of the super-type, but it excludes any other subtypes of the super-type, so it isn't the same as just using the super-type.

An intersection type is exactly the concept, but using intersection instead of union. This means the things you could do with a value in a type I that is the intersection of types A and B are the operations that work on As *plus* the operations that work on Bs; anything in I is guaranteed to be both an A and a B, so it can safely be given to either kind of operation.

These also wouldn't be very interesting in languages with Haskell-like type systems. Because concrete types are disjoint<sup>2</sup>, any non-trivial intersection is empty. But again, type class constraints can provide something a bit like an intersection type; if you add multiple type class constraints to the same type variable, then the only values that can be used where that type variable is expected are of types that are in the "intersection" of all the type classes, and the operations you can use on such values are the operations that work with any of the type classes.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could imagine combining an operation `A -> C` and an operation `B -> D` to get an operation `(A | B) -> (C | D)`, much like you can use the tags of sum types to "route" a sum type to the appropriate operation. But it gets murky for fully general union types. If A and B overlap (and overlapping types enter the fray as soon as you've got union types), then which operation do you invoke on a value in the overlapping region? If you can tell whether it's an A or a B then you've really got a sum type rather than a union type, and if you apply some arbitrary resolution strategy like picking the `A -> C` operation because `A` was listed earlier in the union type's definition, then things work fine in simple cases but get very confusing if you've got types like `(A | B) & (B | A)` (where I'm using `&` to denote intersection).

<sup>2</sup> Although the "disjoint types" point is debatable. In types like `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` you could justifiably argue that the `Nothing` is the "same value" even for different `a`. If so, then the union of `Maybe String` and `Maybe Integer` only contains one `Nothing` (rather than both the `Nothing` that is "no string" and the `Nothing` that is "no integer"). And the intersection of `Maybe String` and `Maybe Integer` contains only one value, that being `Nothing`.

Comment: How should we interpret intersection and union, while function types and polymorphism exist? For example, Can we consider the `id` function  belongs to both `Int -> Int` and `String -> String` type, hence belongs to `Int->Int & String->String`?

Comment: For union types, could there also be some construct that, maybe partially, distinguish which "kind" of value we are given and extract  it out? For example, like `{String, null}`, could we first check whether a given is a `String`, and extract a value of type `String` if this is the case?

Comment: @suhorng For your first question, a type like (Int->Int & String->String) is what the literature call an "intersection type". The id function satisfies this condition, so <code>id</code> is a subtype of (Int->Int & String->String).

Comment: @suhorng For you second question, yes you can check whether a given object is a String, just as you can do a "case" in ML or Haskell. But you don't actually need to "extract it out" for union types. A String will always be a String object. It is not wrapped in another type like  ML or Haskell.

Comment: So in general, a tagged union uses value constructors to pattern-match to differentiate its components. But can an untagged union similarly use type annotations to differentiate its components? I saw this idea in this article: http://calculist.blogspot.com.au/2008/02/true-unions.html

Does that make the untagged union actually tagged in the type-universe? What are the effects of this?

In another article, I saw that untagged unions can be simulated with datakinds.

Comment: You mentioned this "Because concrete types are disjoint" in your answer. Why is this so? Why did Haskell like typesystem like this? And can there be an improvement/extension that allows union/intersection types to be useful? Is it because of type-inferencing?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Basically for that to work, values in the untagged union have to be accompanied by runtime type information. But wouldn't such a runtime type tag basically be the same role as a constructor tag? I would regard "untagged union" types that worked this way as essentially syntactic sugar for discriminated union types; the only differences come in when you allow overlapping unions, and the type tagging tells you the runtime type of the value, rather than "which side" of the union it came from.

Comment: @Ben that is interesting. What about existentials that are type-class constrained, would you consider that related to an untagged union type as well?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Ah yes, existentials are actually very close to how I would consider "true" untagged unions to work, if you consider it a union of all the types in the class. As with the rest of Haskell's typing, you can't "switch" on the type at runtime, you can only invoke operations that are guaranteed to work for *any* value in the union of the type class' member types. And Haskell's normal type class rules prevent such unions from overlapping, which reinforces my idea that it's the overlapping that would get in the way of a sound Haskell-like type system with true union types.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai With a lot of boilerplate, I think you could use existentials to make a "union pattern" with *exactly* the semantics described in that article you linked. I don't think the author would be very impressed though, as it seemed like they were wishing to avoid the *syntactic* overhead of writing the constructor tags, and existentials force you to wrap them up in an extra data type anyway! I suspect they'd much rather have syntactic sugar and still use sum types under the hood, than have true union types with extra boilerplate. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Whiley programming language](http://whiley.org) supports union and intersection types.  If you think of types as sets (i.e. the type `int` is the set of all valid integers), then union types correspond to set union, whilst intersection types to set intersection.

The classic example in Whiley for union types is representing a "nullable" type, as follows:

```
null|int indexOf(string str, char c):
    for i in 0..|str|:
       if str[i] == c:
          return i // found a match
    // didn't find a match
    return null
```

Here, the type `null|int` may hold any valid integer, or the special `null` value.  In Whiley, you cannot perform arithmetic on such a type.  Therefore, you first have to type test to check for the null value before you can use the returned value.  For example, like so:

```
string replaceFirst(string str, char old, char new):
    idx = indexOf(str,old)
    if idx is int:
        str[idx] = new
    // return potentially updated string
    return str
```

I've written some posts on union types in Whiley [here](http://whiley.org/2012/10/31/formalising-flow-typing-with-union-intersection-and-negation-types/) and [here](http://whiley.org/guide/typing/flow-typing/).  Intersection types are similar, although not currently very well supported in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

A type can be seen as a set of values. For example, if `Boolean` is the set of the values `true` and `false`, saying that some value has type `Boolean` means it is either the value `true` or `false`.

Note that some types, like `String`, can have infinitely many possible values.

As you probably know, union and intersection are set operations, and hence they apply to types as well. For example, when one has types T1 = {male, female} and T2 = {not-applicable} one can build the type T3 = T1 \union T2 = {male, female, not-applicable}. An example where this type would be useful would be answers to the question: "What is the gender of your first born child?" Since some people don't have any children, they could answer: not-applicable.