# Java: a datastructure filled with interface elements - how to force classes that implement the interface to implement compareTo()?

Tags: java, inheritance

I got a built in interface called **Bicycle** (and I am not allowed to add or change anything in it),

and I created a data structure filled with Bicycle elements in it.

I need that the Bicycle elements will be able to be sorted in different ways, the decision how exactly they will be sorted in the data structure has to be upon *the class that implements the interface Bicycle.* (or any other way that doesn't have to make any change in Bicycle interface)

I read on the internet that I need to write something like this:

```
Public class BicycleDataStructure <Bicycle extends Comparable<Bicycle>>
```

and then I can use *compareTo()* function on Bicycle elements in the data structure. But, When I create a class like:

```
SportBicycle implements Bicycle
```

Java doesn't tell me that I need to add implementation of *compareTo()* function, so how it will know by which parameter to compare it? I think I do something wrong.. 
Thank you for your help.

Edit: code -

```
public class BicycleDataStructure<T extends Comparable<Bicycle>> {
protected List<Bicycle> dataStructure;
protected Bicycle max;

public BicycleDataStructure() {
    this.dataStructure= new ArrayList<>();
    this.max = null;

}

public void addBicycle(Bicycle b1) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dataStructure.size(); i++) {
        Bicycle b = dataStructure.get(i);

        if (b1.compareTo(b) < 0) {
            this.dataStructure.add(i, b1);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

and the interface-

```
public interface Bicycle{

public int getModel();

public String getColor();

public String getBrand();

public int getSize();
```

}

Comment: Just use a `List<Bicycle>` and sort with a `Comparator<Bicycle>`... Or do you need something more complicated than that?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix I need to compare one by one in order to add the elements in increasing order and improve time complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should change the generic type of your data structure class as follows:

```
public class BicycleDataStructure<T extends Bicycle & Comparable<T>>
```

This is called an [intersection bound type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653678/union-types-and-intersection-types/5987198#5987198), and it tells the compiler that the data structure will hold instances of a type that is both a subtype of `Bicycle` and `Comparable<T>`. This avoids the need to create a subtype of `Bicycle` just to express that it's also `Comparable` of that subtype.

Then, you should make both your `dataStructure` and `max` attributes use the generic type `T`:

```
protected List<T> dataStructure;
protected T max;
```

Then, in your `add` method, the `b1` argument and `b` local variable should also be of type `T`. This is the code:

```
public class BicycleDataStructure<T extends Bycycle & Comparable<T>> {

    protected List<T> dataStructure;

    protected T max;

    public BicycleDataStructure() {
        this.dataStructure = new ArrayList<>();
        this.max = null;    
    }

    public void addBicycle(T b1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataStructure.size(); i++) {
            T b = dataStructure.get(i);

            if (b1.compareTo(b) < 0) {
                this.dataStructure.add(i, b1);
                break;
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile. Your list and addBicycle() method allow references to objects that are not Bicycles. Pulling a Bicycle out of a list of not-necessarily-bicycles should be a compile error.

Comment: That should compile, but it creates a data structure that does not necessarily contain Bicycles. The data structure's name and the stated intent of the OP was that it would contain Bicycles. Presumably there are other methods besides `add()`, and presumably some of them would have to do with Bicycles.

Comment: A subinterface implementing `Comparable` is simpler, ensures that implementing classes must implement `compareTo()`, and easily works with any Java algorithm or data structure requiring comparison.

Comment: @Andy With all due respect, that is totally debatable and a matter of taste and opinion. There's absolutely no scientific way to demonstrate that a subinterface implementing `Comparable` is simpler. On the contrary, I might say that introducing a new type just to make your type `Comparable` is boilerplate and counter-productive. OP just wants his data structure's elements to be both `Bicycle` subtypes and also `Comparable`, and this is the simplest way to achieve that.

Comment: Simpler = less code, greater understandability. See prior comment for other advantages. Sometimes a question asks about X, but the real answer is Y.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner can you explain what is the meaning of the symbol "&" here? does it mean that T extends both interfaces - Bicycle and comparable?

Comment: @user7366106 Yes! That's its exact meaning! It's called an intersection bound type. Only the first one can be a class (it can also be an interface), the rest must be interfaces. I will edit the answer to explain this.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thank you, I have never seen this before

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `Bicycle` is being treated as a type parameter, instead do this:

```
class BicycleDataStructure <T extends Comparable<Bicycle>> {...}
```

Now `T` is the type parameter and `Bicycle` refers to the interface type.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, it raises a red line under compareTo() method and says that it is undefined for type Bicycle

Comment: can you show your bicycle interface? and your implementation of the `compareTo`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't modify the Bicycle interface, you can extend it.

```
public interface ComparableBicycle extends Bicycle, Comparable<ComparableBicycle> {
}
```

Your SportBicycle class can implement ComparableBicycle and still be an instance of Bicycle. The compiler will require you to implement `compareTo()`.

This will result in an error:

```
public class SportBicycle implements ComparableBicycle {

    // ... Implementations of Bicycle methods ...
}
```

Until you add `compareTo()`:

```
public class SportBicycle implements ComparableBicycle {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableBicycle o) {
        // TODO: Make the comparison
        return 0;
    } 

    // ... Implementations of Bicycle methods ...
}
```

Comment: So I need that SportBicycle will implement 2 interfaces - Bicycle and ComparableBicycle?

Comment: @user7366106: He beat me to it.  ComparableBicycle will already contain the contract for Bicycle; you will not need to implement Bicycle if you are implementing ComparableBicycle.

Comment: @Andy: Didn't you mean to write: `public interface ComparableBicycle extends Bicycle, Comparable<ComparableBicycle> { ... }`?

Comment: @scottb - YES! Thank you for noticing this omission. I said it was a Bicycle in text, but left it out of the interface definition. Fixed.

Comment: @user7366106 - You don't need to specify both interfaces in the `implements` line. But you do need to provide implementations of the methods in both.